# Why does the disassembly of a shared object file compiled with -fPIC -shared introduces dummy address like "call 4" and "add 2"?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, position-independent-code

Consider the following piece of code:

```
$ cat foo.c
static int foo = 100;

int function(void)
{
    return foo;
}
```

I understand the dissassembly of libfoo.so

```
$ gcc -m32 -fPIC -shared -o libfoo.so foo.c
$ objdump -D libfoo.so

000004cc <function>:
 4cc:   55                      push   %ebp
 4cd:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 4cf:   e8 0e 00 00 00          call   4e2 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.cx>
 4d4:   81 c1 c0 11 00 00       add    $0x11c0,%ecx
 4da:   8b 81 18 00 00 00       mov    0x18(%ecx),%eax
 4e0:   5d                      pop    %ebp
 4e1:   c3                      ret    

000004e2 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.cx>:
 4e2:   8b 0c 24                mov    (%esp),%ecx
 4e5:   c3                      ret    
 4e6:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
...

000016ac <foo>:
    16ac:   64 00 00                add    %al,%fs:(%eax)
```

In the `function` the address of `foo` is computed as 0x4d4 (the value of `ecx` after the call to `__x86.get_pc_thunk.cx`) + $0x11c0 + 0x18 = 0x16ac. And 0x16ac is the address of `foo`.

However I do not understand the disassembly of

```
$ gcc -m32 -fPIC -shared -c foo.c
$ objdump -D foo.o
00000000 <function>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   4 <function+0x4>
   8:   81 c1 02 00 00 00       add    $0x2,%ecx
   e:   8b 81 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%ecx),%eax
  14:   5d                      pop    %ebp
  15:   c3                      ret    

00000000 <foo>:
   0:   64 00 00                add    %al,%fs:(%eax)

00000000 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.cx>:
   0:   8b 0c 24                mov    (%esp),%ecx
   3:   c3                      ret
```

Why `call   4 <function+0x4>` and why `add    $0x2,%ecx`?

**Update:** (added -r flag to objdump, -R flag produces the error `not a dynamic object, Invalid operation`.

```
$ objdump -D -r foo.o
00000000 <function>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   4 <function+0x4>
        4: R_386_PC32   __x86.get_pc_thunk.cx
  8:    81 c1 02 00 00 00       add    $0x2,%ecx
        a: R_386_GOTPC  _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
  e:    8b 81 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%ecx),%eax
        10: R_386_GOTOFF    .data
 14:    5d                      pop    %ebp
 15:    c3                      ret
```

Now `4` makes sense in `call   4 <function+0x4>`, because the offset of this instruction in the text section is 4. I still do not have any clue why `0x2` in `add    $0x2,%ecx`.

Comment: Look up "global offset table"...

Comment: This is an amazing article that might help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70302/Redirecting-functions-in-shared-ELF-libraries

Comment: @KerrekSB @Nick There is no GOT in `foo.o`. Is it created at run time? And internal symbols does not need GOT entries, by the way. It seems that everybody is compiling a `*.so` directly. Does it makes sense to compile `foo.o` at all?

Comment: What happens if you specify `-r` and `-R` to `objdump`? Does it print the relevant relocation entries?

Comment: -c is asking for compilation, so it doesn't produce a shared object

Comment: Relocation is the key to understanding it, a tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30507725/895245

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker will perform the relocation such that the `final value` = `symbol` + `offset` - `PC`. Note that the `PC` in this formula is the address of the relocation itself, not the address of the instruction because the linker has no idea about instruction boundaries. The assembler, however, knows about them and can create the proper offsets.

Let's see how the `call __x86.get_pc_thunk.cx` works. On x86, the `call` instruction uses relative addressing, but the value of the `PC` is already incremented to point to the following instruction. You can verify this in your first dump:

```
 4cf:   e8 0e 00 00 00          call   4e2 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.cx>
 4d4:   81 c1 c0 11 00 00       add    $0x11c0,%ecx
```

Notice the offset in the instruction is `0e`. The already incremented `PC` is `4d4` and sure enough the target of the jump `4e2`=`4d4`+`0e` (all numbers in hex).

Now for the version with the relocation:

```
   3:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   4 <function+0x4>
        4: R_386_PC32   __x86.get_pc_thunk.cx
```

It uses `R_386_PC32` but that is at the second byte of the instruction while the `call` needs an offset from the updated `PC` which is obviously `4` bytes more. This means the correct result is `4` less, hence the instruction contains `fffffffc` which is `-4`. Note that no matter what the address of the `call` is, this offset is always going to be `-4`. The disassembler will automatically add this to the updated `PC`, which in this case is `8`, so it arrives at the `call 4` by doing `8-4`.

Okay, on to the `R_386_GOTPC`.

```
   3:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   4 <function+0x4>
        4: R_386_PC32   __x86.get_pc_thunk.cx
  8:    81 c1 02 00 00 00       add    $0x2,%ecx
        a: R_386_GOTPC  _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
```

The `__x86.get_pc_thunk.cx` function simply loads the return address from the stack into the register `ecx`. This return address in this case is `8`. The goal to achieve is having the address of `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_` in `ecx`. We need to know how far it is from the reference `PC` already in `ecx` and add that distance. For this the `R_386_GOTPC` relocation is used, but that will give an offset from address `0a` because that's where the relocation entry is. The offset from address `8` will be of course `2` more. This `2` is what's encoded in the instruction.

**To summarize**: the relocation offset stored in the instruction is the difference of the relocation address and the required reference point: `offset` = `PC` - `reference`. In the first case, this reference point is `4` bytes higher, in the second case, `2` bytes lower which gives offsets of `-4` and `2` respectively.