# Where are local static variables inside a function stored - in the data segment, or on the stack?

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
void f (void)
{
    static int count = 0;   // static variable   
    int i = 0;              // automatic variable
    printf("%d %d\n", i++, count++);
}
 
int main(void)
{
    for (int ndx=0; ndx<10; ++ndx)
        f();
}
```

For example, in this code, where is `count` stored? Usually, `static` variables will be stored in the Data segment, and local variables are stored on the stack.

Comment: It has "static" storage just like global variables.

Comment: you can read linker manual or ld file to see where your data goes to, eg: static to section .bss, while const types to .rodata. while .stack only specifies the area and size of stack

Comment: Dupe? [**Where do static local variables go**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703886/where-do-static-local-variables-go?rq=1)

Answer (score 7):

Formally, variables declared inside of a function as `static` have **static storage duration**, which means their lifetime is the lifetime of the entire program.

The C standard says nothing about stacks or segments as those are implementation details.  That being said, on Linux initialized `static` variables are typically placed in the .data section while uninitialized or 0 initialized variables are stored in the .bss section.