# Can you find the memory for a local character array in a function using objdump?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, objdump

If I define a local character array within a function and then use objdump to grab the assembly code for that particular function, can I find the memory for that array within the assembly code?

This is a question I have for a homework assignment.

Comment: huh what? You can figure out where the array resides in memory at runtime by looking at the assembly code. But since the array is a run-time concept, then you won't be able to get any values stored in the array - that just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well, you can at least find its memory position at runtime in a relative sense in this day and age of ASLR.  That said, if your array has a non-zero initializer, that data is likely to be found somewhere in the executable, yes.

Comment: I have made a small relocation tutorial at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30507725/895245

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, as long as your array has a non-zero initializer, you should be able to find it.  Here's an example I made for ARM:

```
char function(int i)
{
    char arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    return arr[i];
}
```

Build it:

```
$ clang -O2 -Wall -c -o example.o example.c
```

Disassemble the output:

```
$ objdump -d example.o

example.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <function>:
   0:   e59f1004    ldr r1, [pc, #4]    ; c <function+0xc>
   4:   e7d10000    ldrb    r0, [r1, r0]
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
   c:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
```

Hmm - notice that `.word 0x0000000` at offset `0xc`?  That's going to be fixed up by the linker to point to the array.  Let's go check out the relocation table:

```
$ objdump -r example.o 

example.o:     file format elf32-littlearm

RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET   TYPE              VALUE 
00000008 R_ARM_V4BX        *ABS*
0000000c R_ARM_ABS32       .rodata.cst8
```

Aha!  The word at `0xc` is going to get fixed up with an absolute pointer to the `.rodata.cst8` section - that sounds like what we want.  Let's take a peek:

```
$ objdump -s -j .rodata.cst8  example.o 

example.o:     file format elf32-littlearm

Contents of section .rodata.cst8:
 0000 01020304 05060708                    ........
```

And there you have the contents of the array!

Answer (score 1):

A local array is allocated on stack in run-time only (when the function is entered). So it doesn't present in executable.

An exception would be a `static` array.