# Invalid operands for binary AND (&)

Tags: gcc, assembly, ld, gnu-assembler

I have this "assembly" file (containing only [directives](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html#SEC67))

```
// declare protected region as somewhere within the stack
.equiv prot_start, $stack_top & 0xFFFFFF00 - 0x1400
.equiv prot_end,   $stack_top & 0xFFFFFF00 - 0x0C00
```

Combined with this linker script:

```
SECTIONS {
   "$stack_top"   = 0x10000;
}
```

Assembling produces this output

```
file.s: Assembler messages:
file.s: Error: invalid operands (*UND* and *ABS* sections) for `&' when setting `prot_start'
file.s: Error: invalid operands (*UND* and *ABS* sections) for `&' when setting `prot_end'
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Possibly another `$` or two?

Comment: @FrankKotler: I was under the impression the dollars had no effect, and were in my codebase for legacy reasons. Is that no so?

Comment: I don't think that's true, but I'm not certain. I'm better with Nasm syntax.

Comment: @FrankKotler `$` are valid symbol name characters in GAS x86 ELF https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html "On most machines, you can also use $ in symbol names", that should not be the issue. That should have been minimized out of the question ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Darn:

> ### [Infix Operators](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html#SEC66)
>
> Infix operators take two arguments, one on either side. Operators have precedence, but operations with equal precedence are performed left to right. **Apart from `+` or `-`, both arguments must be absolute**, and the result is absolute.

Answer (score 3):

**Why it is not possible?**

You have linked to the GAS docs, but what is the rationale for that inability?

Answer: GAS must communicate operations to the linker through the ELF object file, and the only things that can be conveyed like this are `+` and `-` (`-` is just `+` a negative value). So this is a fundamental limition of the ELF format, and not just lazyness from GAS devs.

When GAS compiles to the object file, a link step will follow, and it is the relocation which will determine the final value of the symbol.

Question: why can `+` be conveyed, but not `&`?

Answer: because `+` is transitive: `(a + b) + c == a + (b + c)` but `+` and `&` are not "transitive together": `(a & b) + c!= a & (b + c)`.

Let us see how `+` is conveyed through the ELF format to convince ourselves that `&` is not possible.

First learn what relocation is if you are not familiar with it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30507725/895245

Let's minimize your example with another that would generate the same error:

```
a: .long s
b: .long s + 0x12345678
/* c: .long s & 1 */
s:
```

Compile and decompile:

```
as --32 -o main.o main.S
objdump -dzr main.o
```

The output contains:

```
00000000 <a>:
   0:   08 00                   or     %al,(%eax)
            0: R_386_32 .text
   2:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)

00000004 <b>:
   4:   80 56 34 12             adcb   $0x12,0x34(%esi)
            4: R_386_32 .text
```

Ignore the disassembly since this is not code, and look just at the symbols, bytes and relocations.

We have two `R_386_32` relocations. From the System V ABI for IA-32 (which defines the ELF format), that type of relocation is calculated as:

```
S + A
```

where:

- `S`: the value *before* relocation in the object file.

  Value of `a` before relocation == `08 00 00 00` == `8` in little endian

  Value of `b` before relocation == `80 56 34 12` == `0x12345680` in little endian
- `A`: addend, a field of the rellocation entry, here `0` (not shown by `objdump`), so lets just forget about it.

When relocation happens:

- `a` will be replaced with:

  ```
  address of text section + 8
  ```

  There is a `+ 8` because `s:` is the 8th byte of the text section, preceded by 2 longs.
- `b` will be replaced with:

  ```
   address of text section + (0x12345678 + 8)
   ==
   address of text section + 0x12345680
  ```

  Aha, so that is why `0x12345680` appeared on the object file!

So as we've just seen, it is possible to express `+` on the ELF file by just adding to the actual offset.

But it would not possible to express `&` with this mechanism (or any other that I know of), because we don't what the address of the text section will be after relocation, so we can't apply `&` to it.