# Why do ELF object files contain dummy addresses for string literals and stdlib functions?

Tags: gcc, assembly, disassembly

I wrote this Hello World in C :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello world !\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling with gcc to assembly code 
I get this :

```
    .file   "file.c"
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "Hello world !"
    .section    .text.unlikely,"ax",@progbits
.LCOLDB1:
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.LHOTB1:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB11:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    call    puts
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE11:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE1:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTE1:
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.9.2 20150304 (prerelease)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

No problem here. But now, I want to compare the assembly code with a code disassembled by objdump :

For the main function I get this :

```
0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
   4:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
            5: R_X86_64_32  .rodata.str1.1
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  e <main+0xe>
            a: R_X86_64_PC32    puts-0x4
   e:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  10:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  14:   c3                      retq
```

I don't understand two things :

Why move the number 0 on `edi` means to load the string "Hello world" ?

Moreover, the instruction `callq` call the address `e`. But the instruction at the addresse `e` is not the function `puts` but a `xor`. So what is the real address ?

Comment: That happens because of *relocation*, and here is a tutorial I've written on it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30507725/895245

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that there are various fixups applied by the linker.  When I do an `objdump -d hello.o` I get this:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  e <main+0xe>
   e:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  13:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  14:   c3                      retq
```

However, an extract from `objdump -d hello` yields this:

```
400536: 55                      push   %rbp
400537: 48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
40053a: bf e0 05 40 00          mov    $0x4005e0,%edi
40053f: e8 cc fe ff ff          callq  400410 <puts@plt>
400544: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
400549: 5d                      pop    %rbp
40054a: c3                      retq
```

The difference is that the zeroes for the string offset and the address of `puts` are now actually filled in by the linker.  You can find those *relocation entries* with `objdump -r hello.o`

```
hello.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
0000000000000005 R_X86_64_32       .rodata
000000000000000a R_X86_64_PC32     puts-0x0000000000000004
```

What that says is that the linker finds the actual address of `.rodata` (which is the address of the string) and puts it at offset `0x5` and the address of the library `puts` code and places it at offset `0xa`.

[This article on relocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29) describes the process in more detail and correctly points out that while some relocation happens at link-time, the loader can also supply relocation data.