# Transformation of based indexed mode into indirect addressing mode (x86 assembly) part 2

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm corrently working on changing examples from complex indirect addresssing mode into simple indirect addressing mode pieces. However, I've come across an example from the Based Mode, I'm unable to "transform".

```
movzbl  string+8, %eax
```

I have tried this:

```
addl    $8, string
movzbl  string, %eax
```

After compiling this code, error message pop's up.

Comment: “error message pop's up” is not an error description.  Please always tell us what error you get.  Lastly, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, `movzbl string+8, %eax` and `movzbl string, %eax` use the exact same addressing mode.

Comment: Sorry for bad exspression, my misake. It isn't error message, my output is not the same. I don't know is command string+8 adding value of 8 to string or moving the string for 8 bytes.

Comment: What is `string`? If it's a label, then it has a fixed address at runtime, and `addl $8, string` actually adds 8 to the first doubleword stored at `string`. What you seem to want is `movl $string, %ebx` / `addl $8, %ebx` / `movzbl (%ebx), %eax`. However, I don't see the point in this. `movzbl  string+8, %eax` is fine (there's no runtime addition happening there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lea string, %eax
add $8, %eax
movzbl (%eax), %eax
```

but movzbl string+8, %eax is not a “complex addressing mode”, it is resolved by the assembler/linker.

Comment: @BiggyPoopa `lea string+8, %eax` is as good as `lea string, %eax`, it will result into the same machine code, just the constant value is adjusted by assembler+linker to point +8 bytes further. It is like changing `mov $5, %eax` to `mov $2, %eax` `add $3, %eax` ... you *can* do that, but it's sort of pointless.

Comment: @Ped7g: It's subtly different: `$2+3` is calculated at assemble time, but `string+8` puts a relocation into the object file (with an offset) because the absolute (or relative) address of `string` isn't known until link time.  But `string` does end up as `string+0` with 4 bytes of zeros as the offset from the symbol.  So it's assemble-time vs. link-time, either way it's all sorted out before run-time.

Answer (score 2):

`string+8` isn't a based-index addressing mode.  It assembles to a disp32 absolute address with no base register.  The +8 is resolved at assemble/link time.  (See [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes/34058400#34058400))

`movzbl  string+8, %eax` assembles to machine code with the same addressing mode (ModR/M byte) as `movzbl  string, %eax`, just a different `disp32` displacement.  **See [How does C++ linking work in practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122446/how-does-c-linking-work-in-practice) for some details about how assembling + linking take care of the +8 so there's no extra work at run  time.**

---

You can do this, because **`string+8` isn't an addressing mode, it's a link-time constant that you can use as an immediate operand**.

```
mov     $string+8, %edx
movzbl  (%edx), %eax
```

Using `mov` instead of `lea` makes this point clear, IMO.  The only reason to use `lea` for putting a static address into a register is in x86-64 when you can use it for RIP-relative addressing for position-independent code (or for code outside the low 2 GiB, like on OS X).  e.g. `lea string+8(%rip), %rdx`.

---

The most over-complicated way to do the most useless stuff at run-time instead of assemble time would be

```
mov     $string, %edx
add     $8, %edx
movzbl  (%edx), %eax
```

I guess using `lea` would be even more over-complicated, or you could `inc` 8 times, or write a loop to `inc` 8 times, but that's over-complicated in a different way.

---

For example, given this source:

```
.globl _start
_start:
   mov  $string, %eax
   mov  $string+8, %eax
   movzbl string+8, %eax

.section .rodata
string:
```

I assembled with `gcc -m32 foo.S -c` and disassembled with `objdump  -drwC foo.o` (the option `-r` shows relocations):

```
foo.o:     file format elf32-i386
Disassembly of section .text:
00000000 <_start>:
   0:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax        1: R_386_32     .rodata
   5:   b8 08 00 00 00          mov    $0x8,%eax        6: R_386_32     .rodata
   a:   0f b6 05 08 00 00 00    movzbl 0x8,%eax         d: R_386_32     .rodata
```

Instead of real addresses, the 0 and 0x8 placeholders are the offsets from the symbol value for that relocation.  They're against the `.rodata` section of the object file rather than `string` because I didn't use `.globl _string` to make that symbol global.

If I assemble+link with `gcc -static -m32 -nostdlib foo.S` and disassemble, I get:

```
 8048098:       b8 a9 80 04 08          mov    $0x80480a9,%eax
 804809d:       b8 b1 80 04 08          mov    $0x80480b1,%eax
 80480a2:       0f b6 05 b1 80 04 08    movzbl 0x80480b1,%eax
```

Notice how the absolute address to load from is right there in the last 4 bytes of the `movzbl` (in little-endian), the same 4-byte value that's an immediate for the `b8` opcode (mov-imm32-to-eax).

Also notice how `string` and `string+8` just result in different address bytes but the same opcode.