# nasm: error: instruction not supported in 16-bit mode

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am following this example. But I got this error. Does anybody know how to fix this problem? I am running on Mac OS X 10.14.1.

```
$ nasm -o hello_world.o hello_world.asm
hello_world.asm:8: error: instruction not supported in 16-bit mode
hello_world.asm:9: error: instruction not supported in 16-bit mode
hello_world.asm:10: error: instruction not supported in 16-bit mode
hello_world.asm:11: error: instruction not supported in 16-bit mode
hello_world.asm:15: error: instruction not supported in 16-bit mode
hello_world.asm:16: error: instruction not supported in 16-bit mode
$ nasm --version
NASM version 2.13.03 compiled on Feb  8 2018
```

[How does C++ linking work in practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122446/how-does-c-linking-work-in-practice/30507725#30507725)

```
section .data
hello_world db "Hello world!", 10
section .text
global _start
_start:

; sys_write
mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, hello_world
mov rdx, 13
syscall

; sys_exit
mov rax, 60
mov rdi, 0
syscall
```

Comment: Those are Linux system-call numbers.  That won't work on OS X.

Comment: Try `-f macho64` to get nasm to generate a Mach-O object with 64 bit code.  Still, this code won't work without changes due to it being written for Linux.

Comment: @Rietty The `BITS` directive changes the operation mode you assemble for, masking the error.  It does not solve the underlying problem (wrong object file format) and is not needed to solve it.  `BITS` is almost never the solution for this sort of issue.

Comment: I fixed [Ciro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122446/how-does-c-linking-work-in-practice/30507725#30507725) use `-felf64`, because the default `-fbin` doesn't work on Linux either.  Maybe old versions of NASM defaulted to `-felf64` on Linux?  Anyway, `-f macho64` is the output format you need on OS X for it to assemble + link, but then it will fail at runtime with the wrong call numbers.

Comment: How to make it work on Mac?

Comment: @user1424739 Fix the system call numbers.  Check out `/usr/include/sys/syscall.h` for the system call numbers (I hope that's correct for macOS).  Note that the error numbers are different, too.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think NASM always defaulted to its `-f bin` output format.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not in the code.

The complete command to compile is `nasm -f elf64 -o hello.o hello.asm`

You have to specify the format (elf64) to `nasm` compiler using the `-f` option.

Comment: The answer to *this* question is actually `-f macho64`, because it's an OS X question.  That will get it to assemble, at which point the OP will discover that OS X uses different system-call numbers than Linux.